# Mongoose populate method on query returns empty array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am having trouble querying my model, and using the .populate method to grab referenced documents of my object. Here are my schemas:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
 firstname: { type: String, required: true, unique: false },
 lastname: { type: String, required: true, unique: false },
 ...
 children: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Child'}],
});

var childSchema = new Schema({
 firstname: { type: String, required: true, unique: false },
 lastname: { type: String, required: true, unique: false },
 ...
 legal_guardian_id: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
});
```

And here is how i'm trying to run my query:

```
User.findOne({ _id: '5b9d30083e33585cc0b8c710' })
  .populate('children').exec((err, doc) => {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }
    res.send(doc);
})
```

This results in "children": []

When I just use the findOne method and return the user, I get "children":["5b9d3f23d1408c5f4e2624f3"].

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please go through `https://medium.com/@nicknauert/mongooses-model-populate-b844ae6d1ee7` might help you

Comment: What do you get if you do `console.log(doc)` in the `.exec()`? Does it show children there?

Comment: @Akrion, i get the normal fields/field info of the user, but for children I get, "children":[]. Which is extra weird for me because if I remove the populate method, I get: "children":["5b9d3f23d1408c5f4e2624f3"]. So there is a value there.

Comment: And you have verified that there is a record with an ObjectId `_id: 5b9d3f23d1408c5f4e2624f3` in the children collection?

Comment: @Akrion, yes I have confirmed that.